# How to track app usage time in React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-native-module

I want to track user's overall app usage time (other apps) in React Native.

I found [android.app.usage](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/package-summary) that tracks exactly what I want.

Is it possible to use 'android.app.usage' in React Native? or Do I have to make my own native module for React Native?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey @leesinmaster were you able to find any solution?

Comment: @leesinmaste how did you track?